# Filtering HTML table with JS hiding thead

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a filter for a HTML table, example below. This is also filtering the thead.

```
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Search" onkeyup="SearchBar()" placeholder="Search">
</div>

<table id="MainTable" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
      <th width="2%" style="text-align: center;"></th>
      <th width="50%">Display Name</th>
      <th width="20%">Dashboard</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr class="">
      <td style="text-align: center;">a</td>
      <td>DashboardTest</td>
      <td>b</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


function SearchBar() {
 var $rows = $('#MainTable tr');
    $('#Search').keyup(function() {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $rows.show().filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
    });
}
```

is there a way for the thead not to be included using this JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can search only in the TBODY. 
Give TBODY an id="MyBody"
Change this line to:
var $rows = $('#MyBody tr');
It won't search in the thead anymore.